# Header with a rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

Does anyone here knows how to make a table header like this (refer to the image below)?

[image: table header]

I tried:

```
<thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>Creation Date</th>
                        <th>Week Day</th> 
                        <th>Log Type</th>
                        <th colspan="5" rowspan="1" style="text-align: center">Time</th>
                        <th>action</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>IN/START</th>
                      <th>OUT/STOP</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

but sadly, no luck, the table head is missed up, any help, suggestions, clues, recommendations, suggestions, ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's supposed to be `colspan="2"` on the one column and `rowspan="2"` on others. Use this:

```css
table, th {border: 1px solid #ccc; border-collapse: collapse; font-weight: normal; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
table {width: 100%;}
th {padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">No.</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Creation Date</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Week Day</th> 
      <th rowspan="2">Log Type</th>
      <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center">Time</th>
      <th rowspan="2">action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>IN/START</th>
      <th>OUT/STOP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Used to `colspan=""` and `rowspan=""` carefully as like this

**Try to this**

```css
th{
border:solid 1px red;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">No.</th>
                        <th rowspan="2">Creation Date</th>
                        <th rowspan="2">Week Day</th> 
                        <th rowspan="2">Log Type</th>
                        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center">Time</th>
                        <th  rowspan="2">action</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>IN/START</th>
                      <th>OUT/STOP</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should use rowspan and colspan properly.
[Tutorial](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html)

and here I wrote some HTML Code here, I hope it will be helpful.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">No</th>
            <th rowspan="2">CREATION DATE</th>
            <th rowspan="2">WEEK DAY</th
            <th rowspan="2">LOG TYPE</th>
            <th colspan="2">TIME</th>
            <th rowspan="2">ACTION</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th >IN/START</th>
            <th >OUT/STOP</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>TBODY</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with following, It will be helpfull

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Creation Date</th>
        <th>Week Day</th> 
        <th>Log Type</th>
        <th>
            <table>
                <tr>Time</tr>
                <tr>
                   <th>IN/START</th>
                   <th>OUT/STOP</th>
               </tr>
           </table>
       </th>
       <th>action</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use colspan and rowspan use this simple code and add your css according to your need.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Creation Date</th>
        <th>Week Day</th> 
        <th>Log Type</th>
        <th>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <p style="text-align: center !important;">Time</p>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>IN/START</th>
                    <th>OUT/STOP</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
        <th>action</th>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

have a fun.